# React-native expandable flatlist. Close opened item when opening another

Tags: react-native, layout, expandablelistview

I got a expandable flatList working, but im need to close an existing tab when another tab are opening.

```
  const [expandable, setExpandable] = useState(false);
  const [titleColor, setTitleColor] = useState(colors.blue.primary)

  const onPress = () => {
    if (!expandable) {
      setExpandable(true);
      setTitleColor(colors.blue.secondary);
    }
    else {
      setExpandable(false);
      setTitleColor(colors.blue.primary);
    }
  };

  return (
    <StyledView>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
        <StyledListItem {...props}>
          <ListTitle style={{ color: titleColor }}>{title}</ListTitle>
          <Icon name="add" size={24} color={titleColor} />
        </StyledListItem>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      {expandable && <MyListDetails faqDetail={details} />}
      <StyledLine></StyledLine>
    </StyledView>
  );
}
```

I need to save state of my open tab and close them, but i dont know how can i do that. Someone can help me? Thx!!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of each item having an 'expandable' value... use an 'expandedItem' state value on the top level of the component rendering the list. Then each time one is selected set the expandedItem to that item. And then pass the expandedItem and the onPress handler down into each renderItem.